# What are Sanskrit mantras for worshiping Krishna?

Tags: krishna, sanskrit, bhakti

What are different Sanskrit mantras or verses for worshiping Krishna ?

Answer (score 3):

Narada purana has an entire chapter dedicated to various types of mantras of Krishna. You can check the chapter out for all the relevant details.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here are the sources-

https://archive.org/details/brihad-naradiya-puranam-sanskrit-hindi-by-tarinish-jha/page/n749/mode/2up?view=theater

https://www.getwisdom.in/index.php?mdi=D&flg=N&pmd=W&vip=puran+eng&puran=6+Narad&sec=3&chap=20&cod=narad&pn=1179&act=back1&bn1=chap&bn=page

Comment: Can you transcribe in English for non-Hindi readers?

Comment: @CDR I've added an english translation too